# I dont understand why this error come syntax error, unexpected '$age' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I dont understand why this error come syntax error, unexpected '$age' (T_VARIABLE)

```
int $age = 5;

if($age < 18){
  echo("Your age is " . $age . ", you cannot drive.");
    }
else {
  echo("Your age is " . $age . ", you can drive.");
}
```

Comment: it's `(int)` and not just `int` and should be placed before the integer assignment. `$age = (int)5;` but you don't need that anyway.

Comment: `int` should not be there as PHP does not allow you to explicitly state variable's type (unless it is a function/method argument).

Comment: @JiriHrazdil it shouldn't be *there* but it is valid https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php just not the way she's doing it. Doing `$age = (int)5;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @KenWhite I was planning on closing this earlier with the possible dupe, but this seems a special case and the reference doesn't address anything about the use of `int` and they might not know what to do. I usually don't post answers for questions like this, but she might have thought that C++ syntax (or JS) can be written the same way in PHP.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: OK. I've retracted my close vote. You've got far more expertise in this area than I do. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Ken :-) much appreciated. I felt the question deserved an explanation, which I added a few more details to that answer of mine, *just saying*. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be using `int`, you need to encase it in brackets and before the integer itself, as per what the manuals states.

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

> To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the (int) or (integer) casts. However, in most cases the cast is not needed, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires an integer argument. A value can also be converted to integer with the intval() function.
>
> var_dump((int) (25/7)); // int(3)

So change your code to read as:

```
$age = (int)5;
```

or remove it altogether

```
$age = 5;
```

You probably took that syntax from a prior course in C+ or JS.

I have to state that `(int)` would be required if the variable were passed off/treated as a string.

For example:

```
$age = (int)"5";
```

and using quotes, would be considered as an integer but not

```
$age = "5";
```

Doing a `var_dump($age);` would produce:

> string(1) "5"

and fail as an integer because it is a string.

while `$age = (int)"5";` would produce `int(5)` being an integer even with the quotes around it.